# Relationships with EntityFramework Code First using DataAnnotations

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-annotations, code-first

I have three tables that have the following relationships between them:

```
Account {
   public int Id;
}

Job {
   public int Id;
   public int AccountId;
}

Practice {
   public int Id;
   public int AccountId;
   public string Name;
}
```

I would like to be able to access a Practice object through a Job object like so:

```
Job.Account.Practice.Name
```

The database structure is pre-existing, so changing it is not an option.  I would like to get EF to provide access to this relationship, and I'm sure it can.  I did get it to work by putting an ICollection navigation property to Practice on the Account class and annotating an Account navigation property on the Practice class with ForeignKey, but there has to be a way to do it without using a collection.

So, the question is, what data annotation attributes should I attempt to use to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Description

You need no DataAnnotation Attribute to do that. In Codefirst you can do the following. The Entity Framework will generate the table you described for you.

#### Sample

```
Account {
   public int Id;
}

Job {
   public int Id;
   public virtual Account Account;
}

Practice {
   public int Id;
   public virtual Account Account;
   public string Name;
}
```

If you want also a `ìnt` column (`AccountId`) in your Job / Practice Entity you can do this using the ModelBuilder. The Entity Framwork creates only one foreign key column, like you want.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Job>.HasRequired(x => x.Account).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Accountid);
 //
}
```

#### More Information

[ScottGu - Using EF “Code First” with an Existing Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx)

### Update

You can use [Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to generate the
Models from your existing Database.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I am working with an existing database.  When I try your suggestion, I receive the following:  "Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Practice' and 'Account'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."

Comment: I think you should use the Entity Framework Power Tools. There is a link, now in my answer. hope this helps